# JNR-FFI how to read array of structs from pointer to pointer

Tags: java, c, struct, ffi, jnr

I am trying to interface with a C library [libzbc](https://github.com/hgst/libzbc) using [jnr-ffi](https://github.com/jnr/jffi).

**There is a function:**

> int zbc_list_zones    (   struct zbc_device *     dev, uint64_t   sector, enum
>   zbc_reporting_options     ro, **struct zbc_zone **    zones**, unsigned int *
>     nr_zones  )

How can i read back the array of structures from the parameter **zones** ?

Second question: is the nr_zones parameter declared correctly? The resulting integer is negative, should be positive. I tried using **ShortByReference** ,gives a reasonable result but i do not think that is correct.

I tried the following to read the first element but it doesn't work (gives zero result):

```
PointerByReference zones=new PointerByReference();
IntByReference nr_zones=new IntByReference();
zbc_zone zone=new zbc_zone(runtime);
z.zbc_list_zones(dev, 0, zbc_reporting_options.ZBC_RO_ALL, zones, nr_zones);
zone.useMemory(zones.getValue());
System.out.println("zone 0: "+zone.zbz_length);
```

**zbc_zone structure:**

```
public static class zbc_zone extends Struct 
{
    protected zbc_zone(Runtime runtime) {
        super(runtime);
    }
    public final Unsigned64 zbz_length=new Unsigned64();
    public final Unsigned64 zbz_start=new Unsigned64();
    public final Unsigned64 zbz_write_pointer=new Unsigned64();
    public final Unsigned8 zbz_type=new Unsigned8();
    public final Unsigned8 zbz_conditions=new Unsigned8();
    public final Unsigned8 zbz_attributes=new Unsigned8();
    public final Unsigned8 zbz_pad1=new Unsigned8();
    public final Unsigned8 zbz_pad2=new Unsigned8();
    public final Unsigned8 zbz_pad3=new Unsigned8();
    public final Unsigned8 zbz_pad4=new Unsigned8();
    public final Unsigned8 zbz_pad5=new Unsigned8();
}
```

**JNR interface:**

```
public int zbc_list_zones(@In Pointer dev,@In long sector,
    @In zbc_reporting_options options,@Out PointerByReference zones,
    @Out IntByReference nr_zones);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three methods that will help you:

1. Pointer#slice - will return a new pointer moved by offset.
2. Struct#size - returns the size of struct in bytes.
3. Struct#useMemory - maps memory to struct fields.

So you should create a struct, remember its size, and for every i in n slice i*size from original pointer and use the new pointer's memory in a created structure.